# Read multiple wildcard file patterns for multiple days - pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, wildcard

I have 60 days of files that I need to load and do some aggs. I can load 1 pattern for a given day like this

```
df = spark.read.csv("/data/id/date=20201217/20201217_*_a_id_*.gz", sep='\t')
```

However there are additional patterns and I would like to load the below file patterns for last 60 days

```
20201217/20201217_*_a_id_*.gz
20201217/20201217_*_x_id_*.gz
20201217/20201217_*_m_id_*.gz
20201217/20201217_*_0_image_id_*.gz
20201217/20201217_*_2_image_id_*.gz
```

I've tried

```
df = spark.read.csv("/data/id/date=*_{a,x,m,0_image,2_image}_id_*.gz", sep='\t')
```

Comment: hadoop doesn't have the same set of features that shell expansion does..globbing and other regex stuffs..  better to load individually and  then do a "union all"

Comment: this works for me on spark 3.0. what spark version are you using?

Comment: instead of regex, you can get the required files using hdfs api and pass list of file paths or files to csv function as comma separated.

Comment: @mck 2.0. I've used this syntax in pig scripts before and was hoping it would be the same.